# capture mysql query response using packetbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, packetbeat

I have used packetbeat and found it very useful.

But the document does not contain the response received from the server. For e.g. in case of mysql, I have a field num_rows but not the actual data that is returned.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/exported-fields-mysql.html

I checked the above page and there is no way to enable packets received from port 3306
if **mysql.query** can be captured, why not **mysql.query_response**?

Is there any other utility in beats family that can help in this?

Comment: I hope you are looking for this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/are-the-mysql-responses-captured-by-packetbeat/47408 ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes. that is correct. Can you post this as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the Elastic search forums

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/are-the-mysql-responses-captured-by-packetbeat/47408

You have to enable `send_response: true` in mysql protocol section to store query results. You can find all the parameters below

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/packetbeat-reference-yml.html